# How to Customize Text ellipsis in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-text

I want to display text as below image. So i need to customize text overflow more than 3 dots OR any other way to implement this.[image: image link]

Answer (score 1):

Text widget itself has maxLines and overflow properties. You can use them according to your needs. Here is a sample code that will work for your use case.

```
 Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
        child: Text(
            'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of     the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.  ',
        maxLines: 3,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,)));
```

Here is a dartpad link for the working code.
https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1
I use RichText widget to have a clickable link at the end.

```
 Widget showMoreOrLess(String yourLongText, BuildContext context) {
return Expanded(
  child: RichText(
      text: TextSpan(children: [
    TextSpan(
      text: showMore
          ? '${yourLongText.substring(0, 300)}... '
          : '${yourLongText}...',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
    ),
    TextSpan(
        text: showMore ? 'Show more' : 'Show Less',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
          ..onTap = () {
            setState(() {
              showMore = !showMore;
            });
          })
  ])),
);
```

}

Comment: Yes, but I need to add show more option in that

Comment: @RenikShiroya you can use RichText widget to have a clickable 'show more' or 'show less' link at the end of your text. I have updated my answer with the working code. Take a look and let me know if this works for you.